# Load date from store to combobox

Tags: json, extjs, combobox, store

Hello i am get from server date to store with "url: /book/price" . And this response comes from the server 
`{
status: "SUCCESS",
msg: "операция завершена успешно",
data: [
"500",
"600"
]
}`

This information from "data"  I want to insert in combobox.
I am create store, but don't know what write there:
this store:

```
Ext.define('TPL.store.price.Book', {
extend: 'Ext.data.BaseStore',
autoLoad: true,
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: '/book/price',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data',
        successProperty: 'success'
    }
}});
```

And in combobox i am don't know what write in valuefield

```
{
                xtype: 'combobox',
                width: 350,
                store: 'price.Book', 
                 valueField: '???'
            }
```

Thanks for all answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your proxy should be:

```
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: '/book/price',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data',
        successProperty: 'status' <-
    }
}
```

and you can ommit the `valueField` property if your store has data in array format.

Comment: i am write in combobox  property: valueField:'' ; But in console i am see error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Comment: with blank I mean that you don't define that property

Comment: @user3045654 if you upvote an answer please mark it as accepted if it was helpful to make this visibly to other users

Comment: @user3045654 please do this for every of your questions