# Data fro Store to combobox, undefind

Tags: json, extjs, combobox, store

Hello i am get from server date to store with "url: /author/name" . And this response comes from the server

```
{
status: "SUCCESS",
msg: "операция завершена успешно",
data: [
{
aname: "Pushkin"
},
{
aname: "Lermontov"
}
]
}
```

This is Store:

```
Ext.define('TPL.store.Author', {
        fields: [
        {name: 'aname', value: 1},

    ],
    proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: '/author/name"',
    reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            successProperty: 'success'
    }
}
});
```

This is combo:

```
     {
                    xtype: 'combobox',
                    store: 'Author',
                    queryMode: 'local',
                    displayField: 'aname',
                    valueField: 'aname',
                    width: 600,
                    name: 'aname',
                },
```

But when i am open form with combo i have in console  "null". I am want insert to combo data from store: ("Pushkin" "Lermontov" )

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load date from store to combobox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058702/load-date-from-store-to-combobox)

Answer (score 1):

You only defined the store and not created an instance. Also you must tell the store to load his data.

Do something like this:

```
var authorStore = Ext.create('TPL.store.Author', {
    successProperty: 'status',
    autoLoad: true
});
//Configuration in combobox:
{
  store: authorStore,
}
```

Comment: i have this in console : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Comment: Do you know which file and method throws this error? I don't think it has something to do with my answer.